# AWS s3 mv command deletes the source directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

The objective is to move all the files from s3 "dir2" directory to EMR directory "mydir".

I am using the command:

> aws s3 mv s3:///dir1/dir2/ /mnt/mydir/ --recursive

This command gets executed but the dir2 directory from s3 gets deleted. 
The files within dir2 although moves to mydir of EMR.

How can I only move the files from source dir of s3 without removing the source directory?

Answer (score 2):

Directories or folders do not actually exist in S3. What you are calling a directory is simply a common file name prefix in S3. When there are no files with that prefix anymore then the "directory" does not exist anymore in S3.

Comment: This may be the exact problem. The folder may not actually exist in S3 as a distinct object. When all the "contained" objects are gone, there's no directory object left behind to designate an empty folder.

Comment: My objective is to "move" all the files from the S3 folder to EMR. After the mv operation, the folder will be present but with no files within it. Any way out?

Comment: Why are you worried about keeping a folder in S3? Like I said, folders don't exist in S3. When you copy a new file to S3 with that prefix, the "folder" will automatically reappear.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with multiple objects, you want to use sync not cp or mv:

```
aws s3 sync s3:///dir1/dir2/ /mnt/mydir/
```

There are ways to load data into EMR directly from S3, so you may want to look into those.

Update: I have confirmed that:

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucket/f1/f2 . --recursive
```

Will move all of the files inside f2/ while leaving f2 in the bucket.

Comment: I can see this as a legit answer, why it's downvoted. The OP is using 'mv' command that's why the dir2 is getting removed, instead 'sync' command has to be used as suggested by @chris.

Comment: sync supposedly copies files from source to destination. My objective is to "move" files. Any suggestion?

Comment: The statement that you need to use `sync` to deal with multiple objects is incorrect.